# Putty Session Logging - Not encoding characters properly

Tags: logging, character-encoding, putty

I'm setting up a Ubuntu server using Windows + Putty and want to log all my console activity. In putty I have the following configuration:

[Putty Configuration http://lbjuice.com/host/putty.png](http://lbjuice.com/host/putty.png)
[[View Full Size]](http://lbjuice.com/host/putty.png)

The problem is, this is the log file it generates:

[Logfile http://lbjuice.com/host/session-output.png](http://lbjuice.com/host/session-output.png)
[[View Full Size]](http://lbjuice.com/host/session-output.png)

Notice all the unreadable characters and symbols? I assume it has something to do with the encoding, but I tried changing it in Putty, and the problem remains.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is not so much Putty, but that you're opening the file with Notepad.

Try opening the log file in an editor that can switch character sets (most easily, perhaps, a browser) and try switching around character sets.

Comment: I tried opening it in multiple text editors (notepad, e, notepad++) and browsers (firefox, chrome, internet explorer) - this had no affect on it.